# Exporting gradle project from Eclipse: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Hoping someone can help here.

I imported a gradle project into eclipse using gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse

However how do I export it back out? It is not an android app but I have seen mention of installing ADT to get the ability to export gradle build files in File > Export.

It works fine on my pc, but on any elses' it has the error Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Thanks

edit: Fixed it. One of the files was corrupted, I re extracted and it was fine. Silly